# How do I save list box items into JSON file?

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I have one list box which is filled dynamically.
I have created one sample.json file inside project folder and want to save all listbox items saved into samepl.json in simple `string[]`
format.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    {
         json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.ToString());
    }
}

sample.json
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is some example code that shows how you can create a Json string from the ListBox items and then write that string to file. It then shows how you can read that code back in and re-populate the ListBox items with the original data.

To be able to use the JavaScriptSerializer you must add a reference to System.Web.Extensions to your project. You can do this by clicking Project -> Add Reference... -> Selecting 'Framework' and then 'Assemblies' and then checking the box for 'System.Web.Extensions' and clicking OK.

```
        // Create an example ListBox
        System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lb = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        // Add some random items to the list box
        lb.Items.Add("123");
        lb.Items.Add(456);
        lb.Items.Add(false);
        // Create a new JavaScriptSerializer to convert our object to and from a json string
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        // Use the JavaScriptSerializer to convert the ListBox items into a Json string
        string writeJson = jss.Serialize(lb.Items);
        // Write this string to file
        File.WriteAllText("ListBoxItems.json", writeJson);
        // Clear all element from the ListBox
        lb.Items.Clear();
        // Read the json string back from the file
        string readJson = File.ReadAllText("ListBoxItems.json");
        // Use the JavaScriptSerializer Deserialize method to add the objects back into the ListBox item collection.
        lb.Items.AddRange(jss.Deserialize<object[]>(readJson));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can create a [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jarray.htm) and use the method `Add`,so  you can add the elements from your listbox.

Once this is done, you can use the [method `string json = ToString(Formatting)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString_1.htm) to have a neatly indented JSON

After calling ToString() you can use System.IO.File's static methods to save to file:

```
File.WriteAllText(json, path);
```

Comment: did not understand any sample example to save it in json file.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an example on how to persist the resulting string to file. Also, please read the links provided in my answer.